# Validation groups - one group or field is required

Tags: jquery, validation, if-statement, jquery-validate

I have a form and I want to validate one group (3 text fields) and one text field. When all 3 text fields in group are filled the fourth text field is not require but when all 3 text fields in group are blank, the fourth text field is require. I'm using validation plugin but I don't know how to write condition with these plugin.

```
<input name="name" id="name" class="" type="text" />
<input name="date" id="date" class="" type="text" />

 <input name="first" id="first" class="group" type="text" value="reqiure if #fourth is blank" /> 
 <input name="second" id="second" class="group" type="text" value="reqiure if #fourth is blank" />
 <input name="third" id="third" class="group" type="text" value="reqiure if #fourth is blank" />

<input name="fourth" id="fourth" class="" type="text" value="reqiure if .group is blank" />
```

For now I wrote this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#my_form').validate({
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            date: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please enter your name.",
            date: "Please enter date of birth."
        },
        errorContainer: $('#errorContainer'),
        errorLabelContainer: $('#errorContainer ul'),
        wrapper: 'li'
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: jQuery Validation plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/validate/

Comment: Sorry wrong link: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/